# Angularjs For Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a for loop in AngularJs. 
My code is:

```
var data = $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.rows( { selected: true } ).data();

for (var i=0; i<= data.length; i++){
    console.log(data[i].Id);
}
```

In console I see the output but I also get the error

> Error: data[i] is undefined

I do something wrong? Is another way to write for loop in AngularJs?
Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the for loop to:

```
for (var i=0; i< data.length; i++) {
```

Array indexes start at 0 up to array's length - 1. So if you use <= you will go passed the last index, thus having an `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.forEach` and never think about array size:

```
data.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item.id);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll also try this way